# time greater than another time

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am preparing a small php attendance script which will record the time and date of given user.

I am trying to display a message that if person is LATE after given time php to display a message you are late

```
$CURRENTTIME = new DateTime($data['current_time']);
$CURRENTTIME = $CURRENTTIME->format('H:i:s');
$OFFICETIME  = new DateTime('10:20:00');
$OFFICETIME = $OFFICETIME->format('H:i:s');

var_dump($CURRENTTIME);
var_dump($OFFICETIME);

if ($CURRENTTIM > $OFFICETIME) {
   echo 'you are late tody';
}  else {
   echo 'Thank you for being on time';
}
```

also i wanted to learn the code if i need a result in between time? let say i need to display result if employee is in between 10:00:00 - 10:30:00

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if ($CURRENTTIME > $OFFICETIME)`? You have a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime objects are comparable so no need to compare their formatted strings. Just compare the objects themselves.

```
    $CURRENTTIME = new DateTime($data['current_time']);
    $OFFICETIME  = new DateTime('10:20:00');

    if ($CURRENTTIME  > $OFFICETIME) {
       echo 'you are late tody';
    }  else {
       echo 'Thank you for being on time';
   }
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911312/how-to-check-if-time-is-between-two-times-in-php/15911349#15911349) for how to see if a [time is between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911312/how-to-check-if-time-is-between-two-times-in-php/15911349#15911349). It's pretty much the same concept.

Sidenote: There was a typo in your code. `$CURRENTTIM` which should read as `$CURRENTTIME`.

Comment: OP might've made a [`typo`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818573/time-greater-than-another-time#comment40389666_25818573).

Comment: Seems they did...and I copied it. Literally.