# PHP is date between 2 other dates - Ignoring month

Tags: php, date

I am trying to determine if a day and time are between two others, I have the following...

```
$currentdate = date("N h:i:s A");
```

This returns the day of the week as a number and then the current time in 24 hour format.

I want to check if the `$currentdate` is between 9am on a Friday and 9am on a Monday.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Known problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131527/php-check-if-time-is-between-two-times-regardless-of-date

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should give you what your asking for but I'm sure there are better ways to implement. So basically the time has been converted into an `INT` for comparing and the hours are configured not to have a leading zero hence why `$timeOne` and `$timeTwo` is shorter. I've then used an `if` statement to test days and time on that specific day leaving you a slot to add your code if those conditions are met.

```
function checkDayTime() {

$day = date(w); //0 (for Sunday) through to 6 (for Saturday)
$timeOne = 90000;
$timeTwo = 90000;//Added for easier reading
$currentTime = (int) date('Gis'); //Time as INT 00000 > 240000


 if (($day == 5 && $currentTime > $timeOne) || ($day == 6 || $day == 0) || ($day == 1 && $currentTime < $timeTwo)) {

   //Between those hours

   return TRUE;

  } else {

    //Not between those hours

   return FALSE;

  }

}
```

***Just removed the extra `if` statement as it was not needed***