# How to fetching value between two dates

Tags: php, date, codeigniter-3

I want to get data if the date selected is greater than the selected month.Here I am passing two values one is the month like 11-2016 and the date is like 01-2017 and if the selected date is greater than month that means if 01-2017>11-2016 I need the result. The posting and all is working fine but the problem is only the month is considering while taking greater than and less than(year is not considering).
This is the code I wrote..

```
   echo date('m-Y',strtotime($_POST['date']));
   echo date('m-Y',strtotime($_POST['mon']));
```

The first one is getting correctly, but the value of the second one is getting all time 01-1970

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205966/php-is-date-between-2-other-dates-ignoring-month/40206836#40206836

Comment: You can't really use php's date/time functions if you don't have a valid date to start with...

Comment: but for date its working...

Comment: can you please show us the expected values of the input parameters? also the expected output would be great to help you.

Comment: the expected output that i chooses for month is `11-2016` and suppose am paying the amount on `01-01-2017` and if the date that am paying is greater than the selected month that is `01-01-2017>11-2016 `the result output am expecting to get is 500.