# Compare 2 time which is greater without date in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the result that which time is greater. I mean there is no date only time.

```
$open_time  = date("g:i A", strtotime($restaurant['open_time']));
$close_time = date("g:i A", strtotime($restaurant['close_time']));
$curren_time = date("h:i");
```

`$restaurant['open_time']` and `$restaurant['close_time']` is the result from database. It is coming in 24 hour format like 22:30, 10:20.

What i want exactly.

```
if(($current_time > $open_time) &&  ($current_time < $close_time)
{
   echo "Opened";
}
else
{
   echo "Closed";
}
```

If `current_time` is `2:00 AM` and `open_time` is `11:00 AM` then the result should echo Closed. And like this if `current_time` is `1:00 PM` and closed_time is `11:00 PM` then the result should echo Opened. Hope i explained well. Please ask if you have any doubt in my question.

**You can solve thus using 24 hour format time also. But remember you can add date but virtually not from database. You can use to get the greater time**

Comment: whats happening now? if there is no date then it just numbers comparison . is it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if time is between two times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911312/how-to-check-if-time-is-between-two-times-in-php)

Comment: Using date that I have done. But there is no date in my database. Hope you understood @zod

Comment: you have only time in database can you tell whats the value for open & close

Comment: Already given in question. Open time 11: 00 and close time 22:00. Like this. @omi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set correct [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) and should work.

```
$restaurant = [
    'open_time' => '11:00',
    'close_time' => '22:00'
];

$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$now = new DateTime('now', $timeZone);
$open = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $restaurant['open_time'], $timeZone);
$close = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $restaurant['close_time'], $timeZone);

$working_now = ($now > $open && $now < $close);

if ($working_now) {
    echo 'open';
} else {
    echo 'closed';
}
```

You can play with it in [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25ae47ae749af7462dba7d45855278bb638fd2d2) - uncomment the test line to change current time.

If it's open through midnight you might need additional logic there:

```
if ($open > $close) {
    if ($now > $close) {
        $close->modify('+1 day');
    } else {
        $open->modify('-1 day');
    }
}

$working_now = ...
```