# Using date("H"); to define minutes PHP

Tags: php

What I want to achieve is to make a div appear at a set time, which I've achieved (go me), My problem is with my current code I can only set the time in hours. I'd like to be able to set it in hours/minutes.

For example make the div appear between 9am and 10:30am. (Currently, I can only make it appear on "hours" only, so 9am to 10am for example.)

Here is where I set the time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$currentHour = date("H");
$day = date("1");
$nineAlertStart = 9;
$nineAlertEnd = 10;
```

Here is the function to display div on set time:

```
if ($currentHour >= $nineAlertStart && $currentHour < $nineAlertEnd){
          // If we are, set our class to off.
        $ninealert = 'timeOn';
  } else {
        // Otherwise, set our class to off.
        $ninealert = 'timeOff';
  }
```

And finally here is my output to display

```
<div class="alert <?php echo $ninealert; ?>">
    Jade
</div>
```

I know not all of this code is needed but I thought it might help understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Try using [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) to make this a bit easier.

Comment: For minutes, use date('i');

Comment: date("H i"); for hour and minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if time is between two times in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911312/how-to-check-if-time-is-between-two-times-in-php)

Comment: `date('Gi') >= 900 && date('Gi') <= 1030`…

Comment: BTW, `date("1")` does nothing, you might just do `$day = "1"`.

Comment: Okay thanks @deceze

Comment: @JJJ I don't think it's a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following and see if this works for you

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$currentTime = date("Gi");
$day = date("1");
$nineAlertStart = 900;
$nineAlertEnd = 1030;

if ($currentTime >= $nineAlertStart && $currentTime < $nineAlertEnd){
      // If we are, set our class to off.
    $ninealert = 'timeOn';
} else {
    // Otherwise, set our class to off.
    $ninealert = 'timeOff';
}
```

Comment: I'd use the format `Gi` (no leading zeros) to avoid any implicit octal conversions.

Comment: Thank you  - I knew it was something along those lines of the "i" but I could not quite work my head around it

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$currentHour = microtime(true);

$day = date("1");

$nineAlertStart = strtotime("09:09:09");
$nineAlertEnd = strtotime("10:30:00");

if ($currentHour >= $nineAlertStart && $currentHour < $nineAlertEnd){
      // If we are, set our class to off.
    $ninealert = 'timeOn';
} else {
    // Otherwise, set our class to off.
    $ninealert = 'timeOff';
 }



<div class="alert <?php echo $ninealert; ?>">
Jade
</div>
```